# Array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]

Tags: c

I am trying to remove leading/trailing whitespace characters with help below helper function. 
When compiling i am getting warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts] 
how to get rid of this message.

```
  char *removeSpace(char *str )
  {
     char *end;

     // Trim leading space
     while(isspace(*str)) 
     str++;

    if(*str == 0)  // All spaces?
    return str;

   // Trim trailing space
   end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
   while(end > str && isspace(*end)) end--;

   // Write new null terminator
   *(end+1) = 0;

   return str;
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: array subscript has type char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972359/warning-array-subscript-has-type-char)

Comment: That error doesn't come from the code you posted.

Comment: When you get warnings or errors, the compiler helpfully tells you which line number generated the problem.  Most of the time, the compiler gets this right.  The onus is on you to go to that line number and look at the code.  If you don't understand it, you need to point out to us which line has the problem, and supply all relevant code that will help us explain it to you.

Comment: Perhaps you use a variation of `isspace` which is a macro that indexes an array? If so, it's a bad implementation.

Comment: BTW The `end > str` is not needed as you know `isspace(*str)` is false.

Answer (score 17):

The warning may be because you're passing a `char` to the `isspace()` macro. The implementation of `isspace()` may be via array indexing. (The argument to the `isspace()` macro is defined to be an *integer the value of which can fit in an **`unsigned`**`char`*).

I've just looked at `ctype.h` in GNU libc, and while there's a complicated mess of macros and functions, somewhere in the definition of `isspace()` there's an array being indexed.

See if `isspace((unsigned char) *str)` gets rid of the warning.

Comment: Yes that does get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 7):

The code you posted doesn't have any array subscripting at all, but that error is caused by code like this:

```
int array[256];
char c = ...;
array[c] = ...;
```

The line `array[c]` is very likely a bug, because the type `char` can be signed or unsigned—it's up to the compiler.  If `char` is signed, then it's possible for `c` to be negative, in which case accessing a negative array index leads to Undefined Behavior.

The fix is to make sure you never use a `char` variable as an array index—always cast to an unsigned type first, and always make sure that your value is in range.  If you're running on a system with 8-bit `char`s (i.e. `CHAR_BIT` is 8), then a 256-element array will always be able to store all possible `unsigned char` values, and you can omit the bounds check:

```
int array[256];
char c = ...;
array[(unsigned char)c] = ...;  // Always ok, if CHAR_BIT <= 8
```

Comment: Surely it is better to _always_ __declare__ array indexing values as `unsigned` types!

Comment: Actually, the `isspace()` macro may be implemented using an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this warning with that compiler flag:

```
-Wno-char-subscripts
```

Comment: Disabling a warning is only ever appropriate after you have completely understood the purpose of the warning.

Answer (score -1):

-Wchar-subscripts : Warn if an array subscript has type char

Example code which produces above warning.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a[10]; //or even char a[10];
char c=5;
printf("%d",a[c]); //you might used like this in your code array with character subscript
return 0;
}
```

In your code(Which is not posted), You might used char subscript As Like above.

Example of main which produces the -Wchar-subscripts warning in your code:

```
int main()
{
        char c=20;
        char   s[c];
        printf("Enter string:");
        fgets(s,sizeof(s),stdin);
        printf("String before removal of spaces : \n%s",s);
        printf("%c",s[c]);  //accessing s[c],array element with char subscript or else any Expression you might used this
        printf("test text\n");
        strcpy(s,removeSpace(s));
        printf("String after removal of spaces : \n%s",s);
        printf("test text\n");
        return 0;
}
```

But there is No char subscript , in the code which you have posted. tested your code by adding main.  did not reproduce any warning or error.I did compilation with  **gcc -Wall -Werror file.c** .

if you still did not figure , post your whole code.

test Code Which did not produce any warnings and errors:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <ctype.h> //included this to use isspace
char *removeSpace(char *);

char *removeSpace(char *str )
  {
     char *end;

     // Trim leading space
     while(isspace(*str))
     str++;

    if(*str == 0)  // All spaces?
    return str;

   // Trim trailing space
   end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
   while(end > str && isspace(*end)) end--;

   // Write new null terminator
   *(end+1) = 0;

   return str;
 }


int main()
{
        char  s[20];
        printf("Enter string:");
        fgets(s,sizeof(s),stdin);
        printf("String before removal of spaces : \n%s",s);
        printf("test text\n");
        strcpy(s,removeSpace(s));
        printf("String after removal of spaces : \n%s",s);
        printf("test text\n");
        return 0;
}
```