# How get rid of warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to char*

Tags: c, string

How to get rid of the below warnings.

```
 warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to char* [-Wwrite-strings]
```

Here is code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MY_STRING       "drivers.txt"   

void printMyString(char str[]){
    printf(str);  
}


int main(){
    printMyString(MY_STRING);   
}
```

Comment: One exercise: which line produces that warning?

Comment: why your print expects char* and not const char*? That would be logically correct and will get rid of warning too.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are compiling the program in C++.

In C++, string literals have type `const char[]`, not the same as `char []` in C.

And it's better not to pass strings to `printf` as format specifier, it may cause potential security problems.

Change it to:

```
void printMyString(const char *str){
    printf("%s", str);  
}
```

Comment: also i get warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security] ...for the same code

Answer (score 1):

Probably by making the function:

```
static void printMyString(const char *str)
{
   printf("%s", str);
}
```

This does three things better:

1. The function is `static` (a minor point).
2. The argument is `const char *`, since string literals are read-only.
3. The printing is done using `%s`, since it's dangerous to pass (potentially unknown) strings directly to `printf()`. If the string contains a `%`, that will cause `printf()` to attempt formatting, but of course no formatting data is present. This can lead to crashes.

Comment: Can you explain why exactly is it considered "dangerous" to pass the string directly to `printf()` ?

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli What if the string to print has a format specifier in it? Boom, too less arguments, undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
void printMyString(char str[]){
    printf(str);  
}
```

to

```
void printMyString(const char str[]){  //or const char* since that is all that it is.
    printf(str);  
}
```

This is ofcourse more relevant to C++ since it is illegal there to hold a string literal in a non `const` pointer.

You could also compile it in `gcc` instead of `g++`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `str` parameter definition to `const`:

```
void printMyString(const char *str) {
    printf(str);  
}
```