# Going to learn C should I just use my C++ compiler and IDE?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I have Visual C++ compiler and know C++. I want to learn C, would you recommend getting a compiler built for C or should I just use my C++ compiler and IDE

Comment: If your "C++ compiler" is gcc, then yes. If it is msvc, then no.

Comment: It will work but if you "slip up" and sneak in a C++ entity it won't yell at you and let you know that. So I'd suggest getting a GPL compiler, such as `gcc`, to play with. Then you can enforce different C standards via `gcc` command line parameter.

Comment: Meh, if it's effort I will just get a C compiler. ;)

Comment: Are you sure you don't already *have* a C compiler?

Comment: GCC (GNU compiler collection) contains both gcc (GCC C compiler) and g++ (GCC C++ compiler). [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) is the port of GCC for windows. I'd recommend this.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528411/how-get-rid-of-warning-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char) is one example that you shouldn't use a C++ compiler to compile C code.

Comment: One question you should answer yourself first is, what C do you want to learn? Which really depends on why you want to learn C. If you already know C++, then you also know nearly all of C core language, so after a brief read-through of some list of differnces, your quest is really about learning to do things C way, and learning the libraries. Which again boils down to, why do you want to learn C? Do you want pure standard C, or do you want to include Posix stuff, or perhaps GNU extensions?

Comment: Don't learn C, learn C++.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against VC++ for pure C as it's only C89 compliant (although it supports bits and pieces of C99/C11).

I'd go for [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) instead; both Netbeans and Eclipse are available with [MinGW](http://mingw.org/).

If interested there's a (maybe slightly outdated) post by Herb Sutter on MS VC++ C conformance:
[Reader Q&A: What about VC++ and C99?](http://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/)

Comment: Yep, MSVC only supports C89 and we're currently on C11.  Best you can do with MSVC is try to write your C as C++, but C++ is not a superset of C and there are a lot of things you can do in C that you can't do in MSVC++.  (The Microsoft opinion seems to be that C is a deprecated language that's not worth supporting.)